# Replicate-couchdb-cluster is not skipping the dbs

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to run the replicate-couchdb-cluster -d -v -s http://couch-instance1:5984 -t http://couch-instance2:5984 -i -users,_replicator,_global_changes from powershell but it is not skipping these databases. Any reason why this is happening? I'm able to skip the dbs when running from command prompt.

with -i option I was expecting the dbs to be skipped when executing from powershell

Answer (score 0):

From powershell exists a module that do the work: https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/PSCouchDB

This module has a cmdlet called `Request-CouchDBReplication` for replication jobs, of your databases:

```
using module PSCouchDB
$rep = New-Object PSCouchDBReplication -ArgumentList 'test','test_dump'
$rep.AddDocIds(@("Hitchhikers","Hitchhikers_Guide"))
Request-CouchDBReplication -Data $rep -Authorization "admin:password"
```

Here full details: https://pscouchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#replication-request